# Join table rows by GROUP_CONCAT , failed! It's not working?

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-concat

i don't know why it's not working.

```
"SELECT id GROUP_CONCAT(skill SEPARATOR ', ') FROM resume_skills GROUP BY id";
```

i have a table resume_skills, then two fields id and skill.
it return an error like this one :

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP_CONCAT(skill SEPARATOR ', ') FROM resume_skills GROUP BY id' at line 1
```

I haven't figure it out yet. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss comma(,) between id and group.

Right query:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(skill SEPARATOR ', ') FROM resume_skills GROUP BY id
```

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER! i can't believe i just missed the ",". great!